# Rebuilding Nested Array in SMARTY

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I am woking with a nested array inside a SMARTY template. What I have is a set of folders with favorite fabrics inside them identified by sku number. The array is set up like this:
`{"001":{"name":"Test 1","fabrics":{"CC":["5708611004","5708611012","5708611014","5708611016","5708611018","5708611020"]}}}`

001 is the index, Test 1 is the name of the folder, CC is the brand and the numbers after that are the skus inside that folder.

What I'm trying to do is pull out the folder name from that array. I've gotten as far as pulling out the skus. What I'm doing is grabbing that array from a json encode. `{$old = json_decode($current_user.folders)}`.

My code so far looks like this.

```
    {$newSkus = []}
    {foreach $folder->fabrics as $brand => $skus}
        {foreach $skus as $sku}
            {$keep = true}
            {foreach $smarty.post.param as $delSku}
                {if strcmp($delSku, $sku) == 0}
                    {$keep = false}
                {/if}
            {/foreach}
            {if $keep}
                {$newSkus[$brand][] = $sku}
            {/if}
        {/foreach}
    {/foreach}
    {print_r($newSkus)}
    {$fabrics = $newSkus}
    {$temp = $folder}
    {print_r($temp)}
    {$temp['fabrics'] = $fabrics}
    {print_r($temp)}
    {$new[$index] = $temp}
{/foreach}
```

I just can't get the folder name in there to identify what folder the sku is in. So what is happening is that it is wiping out all instances of the sku regardless of what folder it's in.